Integration of SSO using MSAL in Angular project gets 401 returned error after login
I am fully following the example from Example for Angular 16 from MSAL Git. The code is exactly the same with the example except for the client ID and authority. When I login with my account I got 401 error response. I also don't know how to decode the encrypted code in URL. Is it because that my account does not have access to the application in Azure AD and how can I decode the URL? The URL is like localhost:5069/api#code=xxx&client_info=xxx&state=xxx&session_state=xxx and contains 4 parts, code, client_info,state and session_state. How can I extract info from them?


The 401 error usually occurs if the Microsoft Entra ID application is not granted required API permissions to perform the operation.
I created a Multi-Tenant Microsoft Entra ID application:

Registered Redirect URL:

Grant User.Read delegated API permission as you are calling /me endpoint:

Now in environment file replace your client ID:
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    msalConfig: {
        auth: {
            clientId: 'YourClientID',
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'
        }
    },
    apiConfig: {
        scopes: ['user.read'],
        uri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
    }
};


When I ran the sample, I logged using Popup:

The user logged in successfully:

Able to fetch signed in user profile data successfully:

To resolve the error, make sure to grant required API permissions to the Microsoft Entra ID application.
If still the issue persists, check if you are passing valid ClientID.

And make sure to pass correct or required scope in the environment file.
If you are calling any other API then grant and pass the required scope.

Reference:
microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/samples/msal-angular-v3-samples/angular16-sample-app at dev · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js · GitHub

I know where I made it wrong. I set the Redirect URI to localhost:5069 which is exposed by the backend. But this confuses me. When should we use the frontend port and when should we use backend port?

Are you making use of of two applications?

no, I am making use of only one web app. The port 5069 is used by the backend web api.

Okay maybe that is causing the issue
